# How to display a file in c++?

Tags: c++

I need someone to edit that code so that i could display a file!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
     string data; //enter a data as a string 
     ifstream datafile; // input datafile as ifstream
     datafile.open("test.txt"); // open test file
}
```

Comment: What did you try up to now? How do you want to display it? On a console with `std::cout`? Best to read in help centre about how to ask first.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't specify how you want to read and display the file. Thus I made the assumption that output should go to `std::cout`. In the attached proposal there are two possibilities to read: line-by-line as you would read the file in any text editor or each word separately in a new line (input separated by White spaces, i.e. blanks, Tabulators or line breaks).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string data; //enter a data as a string
    std::ifstream datafile; // input datafile as ifstream
    datafile.open("Source.cpp"); // open test file

    // read line by line
    while (std::getline(datafile, data))
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }

    /*
    // read each word (separated by white spaces)
    while (!datafile.eof())
    {
        datafile >> data;
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
    */

    datafile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

There is no error handling in. If the file does not exist or any other occurs no exceptions will be caught.